# Simulate holding down a key within inactive process

Tags: c#, .net

I am searching through google, and cannot find anything viable... The best code so far is as follows:

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")[0];
IntPtr ptrFF = proc.Handle;
SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);
SendKeys.SendWait("{F1}");
```

But it isn't exactly what I need. This brings Firefox to the front and sends the key once, but I need the key to be held down, and to work on an inactive process / minimized window. How can I do that?

Comment: firefox dont responds even if u press F1 manually!

Comment: Pls read what i wrote - it's a sample code and as far it's the best, but not even close to what i need.

Comment: @ojek - It may be sample code, but by using a key which does nothing, you can't demonstrate that it *isn't* behaving correctly.  For all we can tell looking at this, it is, in fact, correctly sending an `F1` which FF then ignores.

Comment: And if i told you that this code was running a matrix you would believe me? There is clearly visible function `SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);`, that doesn't need ny explaination, and there is also a `SendWait()` function, that has no connection at all to the process. So oh well. I need something similar that holds the key and is connected to the process.

Comment: pinvoke postmessage with wm_keydown